# DataStoreでの文字列前方一致の方法

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud

GAEよりDataStoreを使用し、エンティティ中の文字列の部分一致したレコードを取り出したいのですが
検索し、色んなサイト様を見ますと「部分一致は無理、前方一致なら可能」と記載されているサイトは割と見つかるのですが
具体的な方法が書かれているサイトが見つかりません。

GCPコンソール上でも文字列の前方一致が行えるようなUIは見当たりませんし
GAE/Go側にて

```
datastore.NewQuery(kind).Filter("Hoge>=", hoge).GetAll(ctx, &fuga)
```

のようにしてしまうと
目的文字列の文字コードより後ろに出現する文字コードから始まるエンティティもマッチしてしまいます。
例えば"http://10"で検索すると"http://11...."も引っかかってしまいます

「前方一致が可能」と言われているのは、上記のような余計なレコード込で前方一致可能、という意味なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えば'abc'から前方一致で検索したい場合は、
`Hoge >= "abc"` 
と 
`Hoge < "abc" + "\ufffd"`
の条件を組み合わせれば検索できます。

コード↓
`datastore.NewQuery(kind).Filter("Hoge>=", hoge).Filter("Hoge<", hoge+"\ufffd").GetAll(ctx, &fuga)`

Comment: ありがとうございます、力技なんですね・・・。ちなみにFilter()はデータストアのオペ数を減らすものではない認識で(datastoreからデータ自体はGetAllされてしまいGAE側のオペでFIlterが成されている認識)、であまり重ねすぎると性能懸念がでると考えております。go側でhasPrefixを使い自分で走査するのと性能的にはどちらが上でしょうか？※基本的に性能を求めるようなカラムはkeyにすべきかと思いますが。

Comment: いえ、上記フィルタはDatastore側で行われます。インデックスに対して検索されるのでGAE側には条件にhitしたentityのみ返ってきます。
go側でhasPrefix使うのはデータが多い場合は現実的ではないですね。

Comment: 補足情報も含めてありがとうございました。Filterを使用する方向といたします。